# Calling a base class's classmethod in Python

Tags: python, class, overriding, class-method

Consider the following code:

```
class Base(object):

    @classmethod
    def do(cls, a):
        print cls, a

class Derived(Base):

    @classmethod
    def do(cls, a):
        print 'In derived!'
        # Base.do(cls, a) -- can't pass `cls`
        Base.do(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Derived()
    d.do('hello')

> $ python play.py  
> In derived! 
> <class '__main__.Base'> msg
```

From `Derived.do`, how do I call `Base.do`?

I would normally use `super` or even the base class name directly if this is a normal object method, but apparently I can't find a way to call the classmethod in the base class.

In the above example, `Base.do(a)` prints `Base` class instead of `Derived` class.

Comment: Related: [How to call a parent class's method from child class in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/805066/95735)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

If you're using a new-style class (i.e. derives from `object` in Python 2, or always in Python 3), you can do it with `super()` like this:

```
super(Derived, cls).do(a)
```

This is how you would invoke the code in the base class's version of the method (i.e. `print cls, a`), from the derived class, with `cls` being set to the derived class.

Comment: uh uh .. how come it never occured to me that I can use `super` on classmethods too.

Comment: this only works (due to a limitation imposed by super) if the base derives from object, right? what do you do if that's not the case?

Comment: Yeah, this only works for new-style classes, which derive from `object`. (at least in Python 2, but in Py3 I think all classes are new-style, IIRC) Otherwise you have to do `Base.do(self, ...)`, I think, thereby hard-coding the name of the superclass.

Comment: Inside `Derived.do()`, isn't `cls` the same as `Derived`?

Comment: @Ray If it is actually an instance of `Derived` but not of a subclass, then yes.

Answer (score 17):

this has been a while, but I think I may have found an answer. When you decorate a method to become a classmethod the original unbound method is stored in a property named 'im_func':

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def do(cls, a):
        print cls, a

class Derived(Base):

    @classmethod
    def do(cls, a):
        print 'In derived!'
        # Base.do(cls, a) -- can't pass `cls`
        Base.do.im_func(cls, a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Derived()
    d.do('hello')
```

Comment: Note: This approach works for old style classes where super() doesn't work

Comment: Also available as `__func__` in python 2.7 and 3

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer from @David Z using:

```
super(Derived, cls).do(a)
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
super(cls, cls).do(a)
```

I often use classmethods to provide alternative ways to construct my objects. In the example below I use the super functions as above for the class method load that alters the way that the objects are created:

```
class Base():
    
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    
    @classmethod
    def load(cls,a):
        return cls(a=a)
    
class SubBase(Base): 

    @classmethod
    def load(cls,b):
        a = b-1
        return super(cls,cls).load(a=a)
    
base = Base.load(a=1)
print(base)
print(base.a)

sub = SubBase.load(b=3)
print(sub)
print(sub.a)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Base object at 0x128E48B0>
1
<__main__.SubBase object at 0x128E4710>
2
```

Comment: Replacing `super(Derived, cls).do(a)` with `super(cls, cls).do(a)` is not a good way. It will not work (it actually will cause an exception) when you have another `class SubSubBase(SubBase)` without `load()` method defined and you will try to use it.

Comment: @MartinGrůber: so what is the correct way in Python3? Simply `super().load(...)` will work correctly for classmethods?

Comment: @MestreLion Not sure what is the correct way but I would stay with `super(Derived, cls).do(a)` which works AFAIK.

Answer (score -4):

This works for me:

```
Base.do('hi')
```

Comment: The `cls` argument will then be bound to `Base` instead of `Derived`

Comment: what works for me is this - which looks (a lot) like Ned's answer:

where self derives from QGraphicsView which has paintEvent(QPaintEvent)

def paintEvent (self, qpntEvent):
        print dir(self)
        QGraphicsView.paintEvent(self, qpntEvent)