# How to call a parent class's @classmethod from an overridden @classmethod in Python?

Tags: python, superclass, class-method

Let's say I have a class

```
class SimpleGenerator(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls):
        return cls.name

class AdvancedGenerator(SimpleGenerator):
    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls):
        desc = SimpleGenerator.get_description() # this fails
        return desc + ' Advanced(tm) ' + cls.adv_feature
```

Now I have extended each of the above classes to have a concrete one of each:

```
class StringGenerator(SimpleGenerator)
    name = 'Generates strings'
    def do_something():
        pass

class SpaceShuttleGenerator(AdvancedGenerator)
    name = 'Generates space shuttles'
    adv_feature = ' - builds complicated components'
    def do_something():
        pass
```

Now let's say I call

```
SpaceShuttleGenerator.get_description()
```

The issue is that in `AdvancedGenerator` I want to call the method in `SimpleGenerator` passing along an instance of the class, specifically `SpaceShuttleGenerator`. Can this be done?

NOTE: The example is simplified, as my concrete example is more involved. Let's say that my goal is not to concatenate strings.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? If 2, are you inheriting from `object`?

Comment: I'm confused by your using subclasses as instances. They're not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Martjin: python 2, inheriting object. Fixing examples.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The concrete `SpaceShuttleGenerator` inherits from what in Java I would consider an abstract class `AdvancedGenerator`,  which inherits from another abstract class `SimpleGenerator`.

Comment: @KoliberServices: Hrm; beware of using Java analogies. [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), don't fall into the traps of trying to bring Java idioms over to Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately years of Java have ingrained themselves on my problem solving approaches. How would I accomplish something akin to abstract classes and concrete classes, where the concrete ones can call the abstract ones?

Comment: @KoliberServices: Inheritance is fine, although perhaps you were looking for [ABCs (abstract base classes)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a base class's classmethod in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269217/calling-a-base-classs-classmethod-in-python)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
@classmethod
def get_description(cls):
    desc = super(AdvancedGenerator, cls).get_description()
    return desc + ' Advanced(tm) ' + cls.adv_feature
```

The difference between using `SimpleGenerator.get_description()` and `super(AdvancedGenerator, cls).get_description()` is what `cls` will be set to. When calling the class directly, `cls` is set to `SimpleGenerator`, using `super()`, `cls` will refer to `AdvancedGenerator`.

Compare your code (adjusted to use `__name__` to illustrate the difference):

```
>>> class SimpleGenerator(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def get_description(cls):
...         return cls.__name__
... 
>>> class AdvancedGenerator(SimpleGenerator):
...     @classmethod
...     def get_description(cls):
...         desc = SimpleGenerator.get_description() 
...         return desc + ' Advanced(tm)'
... 
>>> AdvancedGenerator.get_description()
'SimpleGenerator Advanced(tm)'
```

and using `super()`:

```
>>> class AdvancedGenerator(SimpleGenerator):
...     @classmethod
...     def get_description(cls):
...         desc = super(AdvancedGenerator, cls).get_description()
...         return desc + ' Advanced(tm)'
... 
>>> AdvancedGenerator.get_description()
'AdvancedGenerator Advanced(tm)'
```

Comment: Can I make class method for all my derived classes that will print own class name (not classname of instance)?
I mean `A2 = AdvancedGenerator2(AdvancedGenerator) A2.get_description()` and return: `AdvancedGenerator2 AdvancedGenerator SimpleGenerator`?

Comment: @Crusader: You mean you want the names of all classes in the MRO? `return ' '.join([c.__name__ for c in cls.__mro__])`.

Comment: No, I mean how to get a current class variable somewhere in the class tree. Example classes: Grandparent->Parent->Child, every class has some class var 'test', and I need to get concat of all this vars. In other language I can do like this `result = self.var + super().get_var()`

Comment: @Crusader: `super().get_var()` would not be a class variable. Sorry, you are still using terms too vague to let me help you with a specific answer. `super()` allows you to access class attributes just as much as methods; `super().var` gives you the class variable from the parent class in the MRO. If you need *all* variables in the hierarchy, iterate over the `__mro__` sequence.

Comment: what if it has parameter? can i just write it as def get_description(cls,params): ?