# Calling custom parent class constructor from a subclass in python3

Tags: python, constructor, gtk, subclass, class-method

I am trying to call a specific constructor of the parent class from a subclass. I tried using the method described [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269217/calling-a-base-classs-classmethod-in-python), but I am getting an TypeError message.

Here is the test code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ComboBoxEntry(Gtk.ComboBox):

    @classmethod
    def new_with_entry(cls):
        super(ComboBoxEntry, cls).new_with_entry()


combo1 = Gtk.ComboBox().new_with_entry()
print(combo1.get_has_entry)
combo2 = ComboBoxEntry().new_with_entry()
print(combo2.get_has_entry)
```

Gtk.ComboBox has several constructors. Instancing it without specifying any will create the ComboBox instance without Gtk.Entry present. Instancing it with new_with_entry() constructor create an empty ComboBox with Gtk.Entry present.

My subclass is expecting the Gtk.Entry to be present. Thus, I need to somehow invoke the new_with_entry() constructor.

Running the above code produces following Error:

```
TypeError: ComboBox constructor cannot be used to create instances od a subclass ComboBoxEntry
```

How can I call a parent class custom constructor?

Comment: Is your subclass expanding on `Gtk.ComboBox` or on `Gtk.Entry`?

Comment: Actually both. I use `self.connect('key-press-event, Foo)` to expand on Gtk.ComboBox followed by `child=Gtk.ComboBox.get_child(self)` to connect to the Gtk.Entry. Then I call `child.connect('activate', Bar)`.

Unfortunately, without `new_with_entry()` the `child` object is not Gtk.Entry but of type Gtk.CellView, which does not have 'activate' signal.

Comment: But in your code `ComboBoxEntry` is just a subclass of `gtk.ComboBox`, not of `gtk.Entry`. I may not fully understand what you mean by "expand".

Comment: I think it is me, who does not understand it correctly. I am pretty new to python ( coming from C bsckground). I came to the conclusion, that I am expanding on the Gtk.ComboBox class and not on Gtk.Entry. My class is subclass of Gtk.Combobox only.

Comment: @Shpenat exactly, and that's why I am confused by your sentence "my subclass is expanding on the Gtk.Entry".

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question a bit. I hope this makes it a bit more clear.