# Python - Cleanest way to override __init__ where an optional kwarg must be used after the super() call?

Tags: python, django

I love how beautiful python looks/feels and I'm hoping this can be cleaner (readability is awesome).

What's a clean way to accept an optional keyword argument when overriding a subclassed **init** where the optional `kwarg` has to be used **after** the `super()` call?

I have a django form where I'd like to accept an optional user argument, but if I define it as one of the arguments `user=None`, then the usual form call `form({})` assumes the positional argument refers to the keyword argument `user`.

Code speaks better than (my) words:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = None
    if 'user' in kwargs:
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(BaseCheckoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user:
        self.prefill_from_user(user)
```

I can make this the cleanest by looking into the actual `Form` class to see what arguments it's looking for, but one of the greatest things about subclassing anything in python is collecting all `args` and `kwargs` and passing it into whatever you subclassed. Also this doesn't hold up to any changes in the source.

```
def __init__(self, querydict=None, user=None):
    super(BaseCheckoutForm, self).__init__(querydict)
    if user:
        self.prefill_from_user(user)
```

But unfortunately I have:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # cannot define user=None as an argument because normal usage
    # of class expects a certain order of positional args
    user = None
    if 'user' in kwargs:
        # must pop now since super()__init__ isn't expecting a user kwarg
        user = kwargs.pop('user') 
    super(BaseCheckoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user:
        self.prefill_from_user(user)
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: One tip: Check for `None` via `x is not None`. `not x` is `True` for several possibly valid values (like empty collections (including strings), zero(-equivalent numbers), obviously `False`, etc.). It's also more explicit/readable, some would say ;)

Comment: I think it's more readable with just `if user:` and the other values would not be valid anyways (False, '', []). Would it be OK in my case then?

Comment: As long as you're okay with any value passed in as `user` that doesn't equate to a logical `True` being ignored, then yes, it's fine.  However, in many cases you can be burned by this. Just be aware of the differences!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I usually just do essentially what you're doing here. However, you can shorten/clean up your code by supplying a default argument to `dict.pop`:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(BaseCheckoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user is not None:
        self.prefill_from_user(user)
```

Comment: Ohh, very nice! I didn't realize pop had a second argument. Can you tell I don't `pop` that often? That helps!

Comment: @Yuji - It's certainly a nice feature!  Don't forget that you can use a default value for `dict.get`, as well to avoid `KeyError` s. I.e. use `x.get('a', defaultvalue)` instead of `x['a']` if you want to avoid a KeyError when `'a'` isn't in `x`.

Comment: @Joe it should be noted though that [`dict.get()` has `None` as a default for 2nd argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), so it can never cause `KeyError` - it returns `None` for nonexistant keys.

Comment: @havelock Yeah that's what he was saying. Use x.get instead of x['a'].

Comment: To make the above more generalized, use ```super(self.__class__, self)``` instead of ```super(BaseCheckoutForm, self)```