# What is the right way to have custom instance attributes in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to add custom attributes to instances of a Django model. These attributes should not be stored in the database. In any other class, the attributes would simply be initialized by the `__init__` method.

I can already see three different ways to do it, and none of them are completely satisfying. I wonder if there is any better/more pythonic/djangoist way to do it?

1. [Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031711/python-cleanest-way-to-override-init-where-an-optional-kwarg-must-be-use) the `__init__` method: the syntax is a bit convoluted, but it works.

   ```
   from django.db.models import Model

   class Foo(Model):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = 1
   ```
2. Use a Django `post_init` signal: this takes class code outside of the class definition, which is not very readable.

   ```
   from django.dispatch import receiver
   from django.db.models.signals import post_init
   @receiver(post_init, sender=Foo)
       def user_init(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
         instance.bar = 1
   ```
3. Use an instance method instead of an attribute: having a general exception raised as the default behaviour is a bit disturbing.

   ```
   class Foo(Model):
     def bar(self):
       try:
         return self.bar
       except:
         self.bar = 1
       return self.bar
   ```

Of these three choices, the first looks like the least worst to me. What do you think? Any alternative?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9415616, https://stackoverflow.com/q/843580

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding `__init__` is the right way.

Comment: Probably, but *do* read the [note about overriding `Model.__init__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model)  in the docs.

Answer (score 9):

I would use the property decorator available in python

```
class Foo(Model):
    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_bar'):
            self._bar = 1

        return self._bar
```

Then you can access that just like a property instead of invoking a function with ()

You could even get a little more straight forward with this by having the fallback built in, instead of stored

```
class Foo(Model):
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return getattr(self, '_bar', 1)
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the @property decorator. But don't you think this is terribly ugly?

Comment: Not if you want to have a built-in default instead of specifying getattr everywhere else in your code. This is just a standard way of creating accessor methods in python, so if it's ugly we'll just need to bring it up to Guido as an improvement for v3 :-P

Comment: Just came back to this question with a couple more years of Python under my belt (2013! I was young and innocent then...). I think today I would go with your answer. The `@property` approach is quite pythonic. On the other hand, django model constructors are seldom overridden.

Comment: And how would you set the value of _bar? A understand that getattr will return 1 when you first asks for instance.bar, but it won't set _bar to 1 (or at least at the tests I made with python 3)

Comment: @DiegoAragão You can use the `@bar.setter` decorator on a method that sets the value of bar, as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).