# Is there an elegant and pythonic way to require inputs for a class constructor?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I've been looking around several posts on class initialization in python (e.g. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164309/python-object-creation), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031711/python-cleanest-way-to-override-init-where-an-optional-kwarg-must-be-used), [Ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)) but I couldn't find if there's a clean way to require certain inputs. What would be the best approach to make a named argument required and throw a consistent exception if the argument is not included?

I would like to have a similar functionality to the [`require`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) parameter of the `add_argument()` method in `ArgumentParser`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, required_arg=None):
        if required_arg is None:
            raise ValueError("Expected non-None value for required_arg")
```

If you want *anything* to be a valid value, as long as something is explicitly supplied, then you can do:

```
_Foo_default = object()
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, required_arg=_Foo_default):
        if required_arg is _Foo_default:
            raise ValueError("Expected a user-supplied value for required_arg")
```