# Interface-Based Programming in Python?

Tags: python

In superclass in `Python`, how can I call the function that's overridden in its subclass?

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def interfaceBasedMethod():
        print "Want to delegate to overriding method in subclass"

    @staticmethod
    def a():
        interfaceBasedMethod() # <-- I know this causes error. But here 
                               # I want to call the overridden method in subclass.

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def interfaceBasedMethod():
        print "Class B processes."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b=B
    b.a()
```

Ideal output:

```
Class B processes.
```

Google search doesn't really return pages about Interface-Based Programming in Python, although it should be common in Java etc. Thanks!

Comment: This is **polymorphism**, not interfaces.

Comment: Why are you using `@staticmethod` if you're trying to do polymorphism?

Comment: @Brendan Long thanks. I updated the code and hope it looks better. I'm Java programmer and still new to python.

Comment: [Read this. Now.](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)

Comment: I thought I saw, at some point, a module/tool that aided with using "interfaces" in Python. That is, it helped to ensure that objects conformed to certain contracts (aka "interfaces"), but I can't recall the name or the scope of the module :(

Comment: @pst There are a couple -- I think one is from Enthought (Traits?).

Comment: @pst: This is not an interface problem though. The method is already defined; the interface won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside questions of style, use classmethod not staticmethod. It passes in the class which is being used.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def interfaceBasedMethod(cls):
        print "Want to delegate to overriding method in subclass"

    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        cls.interfaceBasedMethod()

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def interfaceBasedMethod(cls):
        print "Class B processes."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b=B
    b.a()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inheritance question was answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python).

But in summary, Python provides a function `super(type[, instance])`.

Documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super), super provides a fairly clean way for accessing superclass methods from within a subclass. [This](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) page provides an exhaustive study of `super()` use cases, but this is the run-down.

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

Which could be generalized a bit....

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(self.__class__, self).method(arg)
```

Comment: This question is about polymorphism, not strictly inheritance.