# how to refer to a parent method in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have two classes (one a parent and one a subclass). How do I refer to a method in the parent class if the method is also defined in the subclass different?

Here is the code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.value=num
    def f(self, num):
        return self.value+2
class B(A):
    def f(self, num):
        return 7*self.f(num)
```

In the very last line, I want to refer to the parent class A with the "self.f(num)" command, not the method itself in B which would create an infinite recursion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you know you want to use A you can also explicitly refer to A in this way:

```
class B(A):
    def f(self,num): 
        return 7 * A.f(self,num)
```

remember you have to explicitly give the self argument to the member function A.f()

Comment: I had an error with doing that, when I tried to call a method, which was implemented in C. It expected an instance of A as first parameter and didn't recognize B as a child class. I suppose that using super() might get around that, but I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 41):

Use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

```
return 7 * super(B, self).f(num)
```

Or in python 3, it's just:

```
return 7 * super().f(num)
```

Comment: this is theoretically right, but for some reason, I get: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

Comment: @user1111042: Let me guess - you are using Python 2.x? Then your _class A_ should inherit from _object_, only then you get a new style class. New style classes are instances of class _type_, whereas old style classes are just instances of _classobj_. _super()_ only works on new style classes.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.x and super as you said does not work in 2.x

Comment: Oh, right. Old-style classes, I forgot. You should really be defining A as `class A(object)`, after which this will work.

Answer (score 6):

In line with the other answers, there are multiple ways to call super class methods (including the constructor), however in Python-3.x the process has been simplified:

**Python-2.x**

```
class A(object):
 def __init__(self):
   print "world"

class B(A):
 def __init__(self):
   print "hello"
   super(B, self).__init__()
```

**Python-3.x**

```
class A(object):
 def __init__(self):
   print "world"

class B(A):
 def __init__(self):
   print "hello"
   super().__init__()
```

`super()` is now equivalent to `super(<containing classname>, self)` as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep it simple?

```
class B(A):
    def f(self, num):
        return 7 * A.f(self, num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class B(A):
    def f(self, num):
        return 7 * super(B, self).f(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use super or if you can be more explicit and do something like this.

```
class B(A):
  def f(self, num):
    return 7 * A.f(self, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer at [Call a parent class's method from child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python/41783372#41783372).

It's a slight twist on some others here (that don't use super).