# Question about how python super access base class methods

Tags: python, super

Im still alittle unsure how python super works in the below context. If I have the below code running `super().values_from_datadict()` Is that to say that `values_from_datadict()` is a function that is available within the parent classes constructor?

Or is this just a function thats available in the parent class in which case. why call .super()? Shoulding it already be available via self.

```
class MyWidget(Select2TagWidget):

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        values = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
        return ",".join(values)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to refer to a parent method in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347406/how-to-refer-to-a-parent-method-in-python)

Comment: _"Or is this just a function thats available in the parent class"_ Yes. _"why call .super()? Shoulding [sic] it already be available via self."_ If you call `self.f()` from within `f()`, you'll end up recursively calling the same method. `super` is needed to refer to the _parent_ class' `f`. In this case, `super().value_from_datadict(...)` is equivalent to calling `Select2TagWidget.value_from_datadict(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function that already exists in the parent class, you overwrite that function. This doesn't always use the parent class's original function, but in this particular case, you are overwriting the `value_from_datadict` function with a new function that uses the parent's original `value_from_datadict`. You don't want to use `self.value_from_datadict` because then you would be recursively calling the child's function. The intent in this case is to use the parent's `value_from_dict` via the `super()` and then modify its output for the child's `value_from_dict` output.

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a *type* whose sole purpose is to delegate name lookup to an appropriate class.

In this case,

```
class MyWidget(Select2TagWidget):

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        values = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
        return ",".join(values)
```

the instance created by `super` is little more than a wrapper around both `MyWidget` and `self`. Its `__getattribute__` method uses `type(self).mro() == [MyWidget, Select2TagWidget, ..., object]` to find the first class *after* `MyWidget` that has a `value_from_datadict` attribute, then returns that attribute's value.

Comment: Thank you. How is super a `type` though?

Comment: It's what it is.  Look at the return value of `type(super)`. It's `super.__getattribute__` that defines what `super().value_from_datadict` means.