# Can I call a method in a superclass in a python class hierarchy without using the name of the current class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand that the best way to call a method in a superclass in python is to wirte:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    def foo(self):
        ...
        super(Foo, self).foo()
        ...
```

However, this means that if I change the name of the class Foo or I cut and paste the code in another class I have to remember to change the line that calls the method in the super class. Is there any way to get around this? At a minimum is annoying, at worst is very error prone.

Comment: **don't** copy and paste your code to another class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a parent class's method from child class in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python)

Comment: I wrote "cut & paste" not "copy & paste", there is a difference

Comment: @AJ This is certanly *not* a duplicate of that Q. The other question is how to avoid typing the parent class, this is about typing the name of the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 you can write `super()` and it will fill in the class for you.

In Python 2 you need to write the name of the class. But changing the names of classes isn't exactly a common operation, so I don't really see that as much of a hardship. You just need to remember to search-and-replace for the name of the class if you change it -- but then you'll probably have to do that anyway, because its subclasses will refer to it by name as well.

Answer (score 0):

You mean easy, safe and easily understandable way for everyone (as far as super() goes)?

Short answer: no.

Long answer: yes. There are several ways to do it. One of them is using a metaclass to automate super() creation during class initialization.

```
>>> class AutoSuper(type):
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
...         super(AutoSuper, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
...         setattr(cls, '_%s__super'%name, super(cls))
... 
>>>
```

So, the super() call to the class being created is assigned to the __super attribute. The name mangling has to be done manually, but the instances and subclasses will hit it accordingly. Now you don't even have to call super, just use the __super attribute.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     __metaclass__ = AutoSuper
...     def m(self):
...         print 'A'
... 
>>> 
>>> class B(A):
...     def m(self):
...         print 'B'
...         self.__super.m()
... 
>>> 
>>> class C(B):
...     def m(self):
...         print 'C'
...         self.__super.m()
... 
>>> obj = C()
>>> obj.m()
C
B
A
>>>
```

Of course, I'm posting this for learning purposes only, I don't recommend using it. This is the kind of thing that borders on the [excess of cleverness](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta3/index.html) that some condemn in Python.