# Python 2.3 calling super class method

Tags: python, superclass, super, derived-class

having trouble calling base class function in the following `Python 2.3` script. 
after reviewing this post:

[Call a parent class's method from child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python)

I've generate this small piece of code:

```
class Base(object):

    def func(self):
        print "Base.func"

class Derived(Base):

    def func(self):
        super(Base, self).func()
        print "Derived.func"

Derived().func()
```

code above generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 13, in ?
    Derived().func()
  File "py.py", line 10, in func
    super(Base, self).func()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'func'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: totally irrelevant, but why do you choose Python 2.3 while learning Python?

Comment: Hi, Not learning python. just the first time I had to use super() and didn't go as planned :) anyway regarding the 2.3, that's a long story. you'll have to ask my boss.

Comment: But the point remains, you should definitely not be using Python 2.3 which is ten years old and unsupported. Use 2.7 or 3.3.

Comment: As I said, it's a long story. code that was delivered to countless customers 10 years ago and it's not that easy to upgrade. long long story! thank you for caring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should give `super` the derived class from which you want to step up, not the base class:

```
super(Derived, self).func()
```

Right now you are trying to access the func method of `Base`'s superclass, which may not even exist.

Comment: Oh god! I'm such an idiot. thank you for making me feel stupid for the rest of the day :)