# Calling base class method in Python [bis]

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python), I am trying to call the method of a base class from a derived class:

```
class Base(object):
    def __get(self):
        print "Base::get"

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived,self).__get()

d=Derived()
```

Why does this code return `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_Derived__get'`  ?

Comment: In super, put super(Base,self).__get()

Comment: @GabrielAlberto: nope, that is *very very wrong*, and has nothing to do with the error the OP sees.

Comment: You can call `super(Derived, self)._Base__get()`, but that's best avoided. If you want a method to be 'visible' without the `_ClassName` prefix, then you should not use class-private naming (i.e. don't use two underscores for the name).