# Common code between children which inherit from a parent class

Tags: python

I have a code with the same structure as bellow:

```
class parent(Object):

   def method1(self,name):
      raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses should implement this")


class child1(parent)

   def method1(self, name, company)
      print(name + ' ' + company)
      print(name + '!!!')
      name = 'Thanks' + name

class child2(parent)

   def method1(self, name, company)
      print(name + '----' + company)
      print(name + '!!!')
      name = 'Thanks' + name
```

Here I have 2 childrer that override the method of the parent. The problem is that the children classes share a code that is the same ( the second and third instructions in method1) . Is this code correct even so ? How to improve this code so that the code is not repeated?

Comment: Make an instruction in the parent and call it from the children? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python This way you only repeat the method call but share the functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not realy a single answer. It depends on the code and what you want to do with it. In case of your sample code, i would implement an additional parent function that is templating the behavior:

```
class Parent(Object):
    def _method1(self, name, company, msg):
        print(name + msg + company)
        print(name + '!!!')
        name = 'Thanks' + name

    def method1(self,name):
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses should implement this")


class Child1(Parent)
    def method1(self, name, company)
        self._method1(name, company, '  ')


class Child2(Parent)
    def method1(self, name, company)
        self._method1(name, company, '----')
```

You should also use [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for your class names according to the python styleguide.

Answer (score 1):

You could build another class "in the middle" that is between the parent and the children.

This class will implement the `method1`.

The idea is that this class is grouping few children classes with the same functionality.

If you have few other children that need different implementation for `method1`, you need to define another parentGrouped class that will implement `method1`.

```
class parent(object):

  def method1(self,name):
    raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses should implement this")


class parentGrouped(parent):
  def method1(self, name, company):
    print(name + ' ' + company)
    print(name + '!!!')
    name = 'Thanks' + name

class child1(parentGrouped):
  pass



class child2(parentGrouped):
  pass
```

Comment: @BryanOakley , Thanks for your comment, fixed that. Regarding the parent, the idea is that parent will implement methods that relevant for all children. I think that creation a class between the parent and the children is a good idea in case that we want to group behavior of some certain children.

Comment: This doesn't implement the mediator pattern. It's simple inheritance.

Comment: @BryanOakley , As i said, I've deleted the mediator pattern in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533631/7432). Create a class that has only the definition of the function you want shared, and include that in the inheritance chain.

For example:

```
class Parent(object):
    def method1(self,*args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses should implement this")

class Method1Mixin(object):
    def method1(self, name, company):
        print(name + ' ' + company)
        print(name + '!!!')
        name = 'Thanks' + name

class child1(Method1Mixin, Parent):
    pass

class child2(Method1Mixin, Parent):
    pass

class child3(Parent):
    pass

c1 = child1()
c2 = child2()
c3 = child3()

c1.method1("bob", "bob's company")
c2.method1("carol", "carol's company")
c3.method1("ted", "ted's company")
```

In the above example, `c1` and `c2` both have an implementation of `method1`, whereas `c3` will throw a `NotImplementedError`