# How can I access a parent method when calling the methods?

Tags: python, overriding

How can I access a parent method using function over-riding in python?
See example below:

```
class Parent:      
   def myMethod(self):
      print 'Calling parent method'

class Child(Parent):
   def myMethod(self):
      print 'Calling child method'

c = Child()        
c.myMethod()
```

Is this a proper function overriding solution?

Comment: That depends. _Where_ do you want to call the parent method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a parent class's method from child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python)

Comment: Do you mean "how to access a parent function when that function has been overriden on the child class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `Parent` as a new-style class: `Parent(object)` and use `super(Child, self).myMethod()` in `Child`. [Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/b6ee2520-9c42-4a81-ab8f-9f4d340ee991/?m=Saved%20fiddle)

```
class Parent(object):      
   def myMethod(self):
      print 'Calling parent method'

class Child(Parent):
   def myMethod(self):
      super(Child, self).myMethod()
      print 'Calling child method'

c = Child()
c.myMethod()
```