# The proper way to call a parent method from a child class

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a parent method from a child class. A bare bone example is given below.

```
class one:
    def multiply(self, x, y):
        self.x = 500
        return self.x*y
        
class two(one):
    def multiplier(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        
        ver1 = one.multiply(one, self.x, y)  # here, if I don't pass one as an argument, I get a TypeError
        print('The answer of ver1:', ver1)
        print('What is self.x btw?', self.x)
        
        ver2 = super().multiply(self.x, y)
        print('The answer of ver2:', ver2)
        print('What is self.x now?', self.x)

t = two()
t.multiplier(3,4)
```

This prints:

```
The answer of ver1: 2000
What is self.x btw? 3
The answer of ver2: 2000
What is self.x now? 500
```

I looked on here and many answers seem to imply that `ver2` is the correct way to call a parent method but I don't want `self.x` to change in the child class, so the answer I want is `ver1`. But, in `ver1`, it seems redundant to pass `one` as an argument when it is already specified that `multiply` is `one`'s method (if I don't pass `one` as an argument, I get

```
TypeError: multiply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

So what is the correct way to call a method from a parent class without changing variables in the child class?

Comment: Worry about defining classes that model things sensibly first. The only reason this works is because you are taking advantage of the fact that you can attach attributes to a class object when you pass `one`, rather than an instance of `one`, as the first argument to `one.multiply`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python

Comment: @chepner so what's the sensible way to defining classes? I'm completely new to this thing and don't exactly understand what you're saying.

Comment: Don't use instance methods if you don't actually have an instance of the class.

Comment: You are passing the class `one` as the `self` argument of `multiply`. This makes very little sense... You are not overriding `multiply` so it exists in the child class. Just use `self.multiply(self.x, y)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `self`, not `one`:

```py
class two(one):
    def multiplier(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        
        ver1 = self.multiply(x, y)
        print('The answer of ver1:', ver1)
        print('What is self.x btw?', self.x)
```

Super is useful if you override the same method but want access to the parent:

```
class two(one):
    def multiply(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        
        ver2 = super().multiply(x, y)
        print('The answer of ver2:', ver2)
        print('What is self.x now?', self.x)
```

---

> It seems redundant to pass one as an argument when it is already specified that multiply is one's method (if I don't pass one as an argument, I get TypeError: multiply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y')

This is because when you use `self`, the method is bound to the instance and the instance is passed automatically as first parameter. When using `one.multiply`, the method is not bound and you need to pass it manually. But this is not the right way to go, as you intuited.

> I don't want self.x to change in the child class

There are two classes and an instance which is an instance of both classes due to inheritance. x is an instance attribute, so it belongs to the instance, not to any of both classes. It can't change in parent and not child class or the opposite.

Comment: in second one `self.x` is overwrite` from class One when OP inherit all it.