# How To Call An Overridden Method Outside The Classes

Tags: python, class, object, methods

```
class class1 :

    def method1(self):
        print("Method1 in Class1")


class class2(class1) :

    def method1(self):
        class1.method1(self)
        print("Method1 in Class2")

ob = class2()

ob.method1()
```

This is the question I have...
I want to call `method1` of `class1` outside of `class2`.
Likewise, is there a method to call within `ob.method1()`
Without calling it inside `method1` of `class2`?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805082/11323371) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it's a very bad idea.  You do it exactly the same way you do within `class2`:

```
class1.method1(ob)
```