# How to call a parent's method that is overloaded in child using the child instance with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple question really, addressed to Python 3 usage: How do I make the parent work using only the child instance `c`?

```
class Parent:
    def work(self):
        print("Parent working")

class Child(Parent):
    def work(self):
        print("Child working")
        
c = Child()
c.work()
```

I do not want to modify my Child class as it is from an outside library. I'm looking for something like this:

```
>>> c.super().work()  # can't do that as super is not a Child method
Parent working
```

Comment: you are overriding your work function by inherting the Partend class, in order to use child work i suggest you to rename it

Comment: `super(Child, c).work()` would do what I *think* you're asking? Why not call `super().work()` in the child classes work method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a Parent Class's method from Child Class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python)

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, yes it does. But is there any way not to reference the Child class like super() does? BTW: I CAN'T modify the Child class. (to answer the other comments...)

Comment: @ceprio `super(type(c), c).work()`?

Comment: Oooh, that is good @Iain Shelvington. Yes, please put as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @ceprio Sure, added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call `super` on an object outside of a method call you need to use the 2 argument form of super where you pass the class and the object

```
super(Child, c).work()
```

If you do not know the object's class you can use `type` to get it

```
super(type(c), c).work()
```