# Calling super().method() vs. BaseClass.method(self)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

There are two main ways for a derived class to call a base class's methods.

**Base.method(self):**

```
class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        Base.method(self)
        ...
```

or **super().method():**

```
class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        super().method()
        ...
```

Suppose I now do this:

```
obj = Derived()
obj.method()
```

As far as I know, both `Base.method(self)` and `super().method()` do the same thing. Both will call `Base.method` with a reference to `obj`. In particular, `super()` doesn't do the legwork to instantiate an object of type `Base`. Instead, it creates a new object of type `super` and grafts the instance attributes from `obj` onto it, then it dynamically looks up the right attribute from `Base` when you try to get it from the super object.

The `super()` method has the advantage of minimizing the work you need to do when you change the base for a derived class. On the other hand, `Base.method` uses less magic and may be simpler and clearer when a class inherits from multiple base classes.

Most of the discussions I've seen recommend calling `super()`, but is this an established standard among Python coders? Or are both of these methods widely used in practice? For example, answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python) go both ways, but generally use the `super()` method. On the other hand, the [Python textbook](https://www.zybooks.com/catalog/programming-in-python-3/) I am teaching from this semester only shows the `Base.method` approach.

Comment: `Base.method(self)` also doesn't do the legwork to instantiate an object of type `Base`.

Comment: @martineau I agree. I was just pointing out that `super()` only does so much magic. It gives you an object, so you can call `sup_obj.method()` instead of `sup_obj.method(self)`, but `sup_obj` is not a full instance of `Base`. i.e., you can't assume that `super()` gives you super-robust behavior by giving you an instance of `Base`; instead it just gives you a way to look up methods in the parent class, which isn't much different from calling `Base.method(self, ...)`.

Comment: i think using `super()` is better as it will handle MRO well, more info [multiple inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php) read super and mro section here

Comment: From a code maintainability stand point, `super()` is better. Maybe you decide you want to change inheritance. e.g. you had `class A(B)` and you change it to be `class C(B)` and `class A(C)` with the direct method you skip `C` but with super you just call the parent. I guess it depends. Do you want to call `my parent class` or do you want to call `Base`? One is absolute, one indirect.

Comment: Beside handling multiple inheritance properly, I like using `super()` because it means not needing to hardcode the base class name into the subclass — so it removes a code dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `super()` implies the idea that whatever follows should be delegated to the base class, no matter what it is. It's about the semantics of the statement. Referring explicitly to `Base` on the other hand conveys the idea that `Base` was chosen explicitly for some reason (perhaps unknown to the reader), which might have its applications too.

Apart from that however there is a very practical reason for using `super()`, namely *cooperative multiple inheritance*. Suppose you've designed the following class hierarchy:

```py
class Base:
    def test(self):
        print('Base.test')

class Foo(Base):
    def test(self):
        print('Foo.test')
        Base.test(self)

class Bar(Base):
    def test(self):
        print('Bar.test')
        Base.test(self)
```

Now you can use both `Foo` and `Bar` and everything works as expected. However these two classes won't work together in a multiple inheritance schema:

```py
class Test(Foo, Bar):
    pass

Test().test()
# Output:
# Foo.test
# Base.test
```

That last call to `test` skips over `Bar`'s implementation since `Foo` didn't specify that it wants to delegate to the next class in method resolution order but instead explicitly specified `Base`. Using `super()` resolves this issue:

```py
class Base:
    def test(self):
        print('Base.test')

class Foo(Base):
    def test(self):
        print('Foo.test')
        super().test()

class Bar(Base):
    def test(self):
        print('Bar.test')
        super().test()

class Test(Foo, Bar):
    pass

Test().test()
# Output:
# Foo.test
# Bar.test
# Base.test
```