# How to call the __init__ of each parent dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, super

I've read [the most similar question on SO to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-do-i-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-a-child-class-in-python), which was about **single-parent inheritance** and the only answer that mentioned multi-parent inheritance advised the reader to use **the static form of calling** that method (`SomeSuperClass.someMethod(self, args)`), which, [as pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-do-i-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-a-child-class-in-python#comment85572500_805091) is not always clean.

I am asking for a way to call a specific method `someMethod` of a specific superclass `SomeSuperClass` *dynamically*, as such:

```py
class SomeSuperClass():
    def someMethod(self, args):
        print("Hello,", end="")

class Subclass(SomeSuperClass, OtherSuperClass):
    def someMethod(self, args):

        # static calling (I do not want this solution)
        SomeSuperClass.someMethod(self, args)

        # dynamic calling (I want this one)
        (my SomeSuperClass-ness).someMethod(args)

        print("world!")
```

This is the code I actually tested and want to work:

```py
class Something():
    def __init__(self, a, b) -> None:
        self.sum = a+b


class SomethingElse():
    def __init__(self, c, d) -> None:
        self.product = c * d


class Both(Something, SomethingElse):
    def __init__(self, a, b) -> None:

        # sadly this does not work
        super(Something, self).__init__(a, b)
        super(SomethingElse, self).__init__(a, b)

        # the following works, but is static and does not use super
        # Something.__init__(self, a, b)
        # SomethingElse.__init__(self, a, b)

b = Both(10, 20)

print(b.sum, b.product)
```

Running this code results in the following error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Apparently it's trying to call the `__init__` of `object`. How do I use `super` correctly in this scenario for it to actually call the appropriate `__init__`s?

Comment: For clarification: _dynamic_ calling =`object.method(args)`, whereas _static_ calling = `Class.method(object, args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `super()` function will delegate to the parent *after* the one you've specified - see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), specifically the following remark:

> The object-or-type determines the method resolution order to be searched. ***The search starts from the class right after the `type`.***

So to use it correctly, you should use `super()` to refer to `Something`, and `super(Something, self)` to refer to `SomethingElse`; you can see the order by reading the `__mro__` property of the `Both` class:

```py
class Something():
    pass

class SomethingElse():
    pass

class Both(Something, SomethingElse):
    pass

print(Both.__mro__)
```

Which will tell you the order:

```
(<class '__main__.Both'>, <class '__main__.Something'>, <class '__main__.SomethingElse'>, <class 'object'>)
```

And explain why you're ending up calling `object.__init__` with your second call to `super(...).__init__(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess `super` is just useless then.