# How to call a commonly named method for all instances of a class in python

Tags: python

In Python, is there a way to call a commonly named method for all instances of a class, including inheritance-related class instances? Using the example below, when c.process() is called, I would like all "process" methods for all Parent-related instances to trigger. As such, I would want the output to print "Parent process" and "ChildType1 process" for instance c, "Parent process" and "ChildType1 process" for instance d, and "Parent process" and "ChildType2 process" for instance e -- all simply by making one call (perhaps "c.process()", for example). Or this there another architecture to achieve similar means--perhaps using arrays of class instances? Thanks!

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def process(self):
    print("Parent process")

class ChildType1(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def process(self):
    print("ChildType1 process")

class ChildType2(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def process(self):
    print("ChildType2 process")

c = ChildType1()
d = ChildType1()
e = ChildType2()

c.process()
```

Comment: I think the better route would be to save all the objects in a list. Then iterate the list and run: ```for child in childClassList: getattr(child, process)```

Comment: "In Python, is there a way to call a commonly named method for all instances of a class, including inheritance-related class instances?" It is *your job* to keep track of the instances you'll need to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a parent class's method from a child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-do-i-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-a-child-class-in-python)

Comment: Thanks--keeping track of instances using a list sounds like a decent option. That said, I was hoping there was a more utility-like way to track all instances or universally call all "common" methods, especially in a modular program where the user can build on code by defining new classes, and where I don't want the user to have to keep track of their instances.

Answer (score 0):

If the child method should *always* call the parent method, the solution should be simply using `super`, similarly to what you already did in `__init__`.

```
def process(self):
    super().process()
    print("ChildType1 process")
```

If for some reason you want to do this without changing the implementation of `process`, you could iterate over the superclasses of the object and invoke the process method wherever it is defined. This is a quick untested stub of a solution:

```
for cls in type(c).mro():
    if hasattr(cls, "process"):
        cls.process(c)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of super() but was looking for a more elegant/invisible approach, and the .mro approach seems to fit that bill. With this approach, one still needs to know or keep track of all relevant instances. Is there a way to query the system for that info?

Comment: AFAIK there is no builtin way to obtain all existing instances of a class. One straightforward solution would be to modify `__init__` to insert any created instance in a global list, but this can messy to manage; it is probably better to keep a list manually