# Trying to use the same method in multiple inherited classes with different attributes

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I'm trying to figure out how to roughly do what is below.  Some things will only have `foo`, some will have both `foo` and `bar`, and some will have `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.  I would like to be able to either call `Child.calc(10)` or `GrandChild.calc(10)` and get the attributes set correctly as needed.

At the end of building out multiple instances of Initial, Child, and Grandchild, I would like to just call calc on any of them and have it work, regardless of what class they are.  Initially I was going to do calc_initial, calc_child, calc_grandchild, but that seemed wrong.

Initial Code

```py
class Initial:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def Calc(self, amount):
        self.TotalFoo = self.foo * amount

class Child(Initial):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        Initial.__init__(self, foo)
        self.bar = bar

    def Calc(self, amount):
        self.TotalBar = self.bar * amount

class GrandChild(Child):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        Child.__init__(self, foo, bar)
        self.baz = baz

    def Calc(self, amount):
        self.TotalBaz = self.baz * amount


GrandChild(10, 20, 30)
GrandChild.Calc(10)
print(GrandChild.TotalFoo)  # Want this to be 100
print(GrandChild.TotalBar)  # Want this to be 200
print(GrandChild.TotalBaz)  # Want this to be 300
```

Edited Code Thanks to mkrieger1

```py
class Initial:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_foo = self.foo * amount

class Child(Initial):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        Initial.__init__(self, foo)
        self.bar = bar

    def calc(self, amount):
        Initial.calc(self, amount)
        self.total_bar = self.bar * amount

class GrandChild(Child):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        Child.__init__(self, foo, bar)
        self.baz = baz

    def calc(self, amount):
        Child.calc(self, amount)
        self.total_baz = self.baz * amount

child = Child(2,4)
grandchild = GrandChild(10, 20, 30)
child.calc(10)
grandchild.calc(10)
print(child.total_foo)       # Want this to be 20 
print(child.total_bar)       # Want this to be 40
print(grandchild.total_foo)  # Want this to be 100
print(grandchild.total_bar)  # Want this to be 200
print(grandchild.total_baz)  # Want this to be 300
```

Trying to incorporate super but it feels like something is wrong.  Results are correct but not sure.

```py
class Initial:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_foo = self.foo * amount

class Child(Initial):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        Initial.__init__(self, foo)
        self.bar = bar

    def calc(self, amount):
        super().calc(amount)
        self.total_bar = self.bar * amount

class GrandChild(Child):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        Child.__init__(self, foo, bar)
        self.baz = baz

    def calc(self, amount):
        super().calc(amount)
        self.total_baz = self.baz * amount

child = Child(2,4)
grandchild = GrandChild(10, 20, 30)
child.calc(10)
grandchild.calc(10)
print(child.total_foo)       # Want this to be 20 
print(child.total_bar)       # Want this to be 40
print(grandchild.total_foo)  # Want this to be 100
print(grandchild.total_bar)  # Want this to be 200
print(grandchild.total_baz)  # Want this to be 300
```

When trying to do elder's response

```
class Initial:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_foo = self.foo * amount

class Child(Initial):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super().__init__(foo)
        self.bar = bar

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_bar = self.bar * amount

class GrandChild(Child):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)
        self.baz = baz

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_baz = self.baz * amount

child = Child(2,4)
grandchild = GrandChild(10, 20, 30)
child.calc(10)
grandchild.calc(10)
print(child.total_foo)       # Want this to be 20 
print(child.total_bar)       # Want this to be 40
print(grandchild.total_foo)  # Want this to be 100
print(grandchild.total_bar)  # Want this to be 200
print(grandchild.total_baz)  # Want this to be 300
```

I get

```
     26 child.calc(10)
     27 grandchild.calc(10)
---> 28 print(child.total_foo)       # Want this to be 20
     29 print(child.total_bar)       # Want this to be 40
     30 print(grandchild.total_foo)  # Want this to be 100

AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'total_foo'
```

Comment: I've renamed the methods and attributes to follow a more idiomatic Python style.

Comment: Thank you, wrote it up fast but you are 100% correct, I need to work on that.

Comment: Is your question why you get errors when trying to call the methods?

Comment: I am trying to one figure out why the error for missing a positional argument happens, and two, just figure out the proper way to do roughly what I am trying to accomplish.  Not sure if I am going about it wrong, or if I am just making a slight mis-step.

Comment: You need to call the methods with an instance of the class, not with the class itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: Edited question to try what you said, that makes a bit more sense but still unsure of what is happening.

Comment: `Initial.calc` is never called, so `total_foo` isn't calculated.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much.  I edited the above question to include what I think is the working version of this. Are there any ways to improve?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-do-i-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-a-child-class-in-python

Comment: Edited initial question to include unedited code, and where I ended up.  Still lost a bit trying to incoporate super.  I feel like how I have it above, while it works, may be doing too much?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Initial:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.total_foo = None
        self.foo = foo

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_foo = self.foo * amount


class Child(Initial):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super().__init__(foo)
        self.total_bar = None
        self.bar = bar

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_bar = self.bar * amount
        return self.total_bar


class GrandChild(Child):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)
        self.total_baz = None
        self.baz = baz

    def calc(self, amount):
        self.total_baz = self.baz * amount
        return self.total_baz


child = Child(2, 4)
grandchild = GrandChild(10, 20, 30)
child.calc(10)
grandchild.calc(10)
print(child.total_foo)  # Want this to be 20
print(child.total_bar)  # Want this to be 40
print(grandchild.total_foo)  # Want this to be 100
print(grandchild.total_bar)  # Want this to be 200
print(grandchild.total_baz)
```

Use `super().__init__(values)` to pass the value to the parent class.

Comment: Having an issue getting this to work. Could you potentially make it more clear with calling calc on Child(2,4) and GrandChild(10,20,30) .     AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'total_foo'

Comment: I have updated the answer. You will not get your desire result because of the way you you are calculating values. You are overwriting calc method in Child and Grandchild class.