# Define a method in one line accesing parent class in Python

Tags: python, oop, super

Could I call `Spyder.paws` or `Fish.fins` just this way? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805081/13151511) post in which they do it by just **defining a function**, but I wonder if it could just be done in **one line** by **matching parent method** to daughter's one.

```
class LivinBeing:
    def __init__(self):
        self._extremities = None 
    
    @property
    def extremities(self):
        return self._extremities

class Fish(LivinBeing):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._extremities = 2
    
    fins = super().extremities

class Spyder(LivinBeing):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._extremities = 8
        
    paws = super().extremities    

Spyder().paws
>>> 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parent class explicitly instead of calling `super`. `paws` will be just an alias to `extremities` in this case:

```
class Spyder(LivinBeing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._extremities = 8
        
    paws = LivinBeing.extremities
```

```
Spyder.extremities
# <property at 0x7f46cfbf1d50>
Spyder.paws
# <property at 0x7f46cfbf1d50>
Spyder().paws
# 8
```