# Updating Old wxPython App: Invalid Window Calling Super/Parent Method

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, superclass, assertion

I am trying to update an [old app](https://github.com/AntumDeluge/debreate) that was written for Python 2.7 with wxWidgets/wxPython 2.8. I am trying to make it compatible with my current system's versions of Python (3.10) & wxPython (4.0).

I have come across an error trying to call a super/parent method. The class is derived from [wx.ScrolledWindow](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.ScrolledWindow.html?highlight=wx%20scrolledwindow#wx.ScrolledWindow).

The old code snippet is (*ui/panel.py starting at line 74*):

```
def SetScrollbars(window):
  if isinstance(window, wx.ScrolledWindow):
    window.SetScrollbars(20, 20, 0, 0)

## A wx.ScrolledWindow that sets scrollbars by default
class ScrolledPanel(wx.ScrolledWindow, PanelBase):
  def __init__(self, parent, win_id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
      style=wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL, name="scrolledPanel"):
    wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, win_id, pos, size, style, name)
    SetScrollbars(self)

  ## Override inherited method to also update the scrollbars
  def Layout(self):
    layout = wx.ScrolledWindow.Layout(self)
    self.UpdateScrollbars()
    return layout
```

The error is:

```
  File "ui/panel.py", line 87, in Layout
    layout = wx.ScrolledWindow.Layout(self)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_widget" failed at ../src/gtk/window.cpp(2888) in DoSetSize(): invalid window
```

I searched for how to call parent/super methods in Python & found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-do-i-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-a-child-class-in-python) that Python has a [super() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

So I changed line 87:

```
-    layout = wx.ScrolledWindow.Layout(self)
+    layout = super().Layout()
```

The same error is reported:

```
  File "/home/jordan/Development/Debreate/code/ui/panel.py", line 87, in Layout
    layout = super().Layout()
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_widget" failed at ../src/gtk/window.cpp(2888) in DoSetSize(): invalid window
```

I suppose calling the parent/super method either way is correct. So that must not be the issue.

My system's version of wxWidgets is 3.0.5.1. I found the [assertion check line in the wxWidgets source code](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.0.5.1/src/gtk/window.cpp#L2888). The checking function, [wxCHECK_RET](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__debug.html#ga0cf2ca7d7ff0107197e51e6b434fd0bd), "Checks that the condition is true, and returns if not". So the window is invalid. I just don't understand why as this worked with older versions of wxWidgets/wxPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wx.ScrolledWindow` is an alias for ScrolledPanel since version 2.9.0. In older versions, it was a standalone class.
Try reading up on https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.scrolledpanel.html
as its replacement.

Comment: Thanks. Switching to `ScrolledPanel` does work. Though I am curious why `wx.ScrolledWindow.SetupScrolling` doesn't work if it is an alias?

Answer (score 0):

As was suggesting by Rolf of Saxony, switching to `wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel` solves the problem:

```
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel as sp

class ScrolledPanel(sp, PanelBase):
  def __init__(self, parent, win_id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
      style=wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL, name="scrolledPanel"):
    sp.__init__(self, parent, win_id, pos, size, style, name)
    sp.SetupScrolling(self)
```

But I also want to note that I was able to work around the problem by calling `Layout` on the parent window:

```
  ## Override inherited method to also update the scrollbars
  def Layout(self):
    layout = self.GetParent().Layout(self)
    self.UpdateScrollbars()
    return layout
```

But using `wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel` is probably the proper way to upgrade.