# (PYTHON) Define a member method print_all() for class PetData. Make use of the base class' print_all() method

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, member

Task: Define a member method print_all() for class PetData. Make use of the base class' print_all() method.
Sample output for the given program with inputs: 'Fluffy' 5 4444
Name: Fluffy
Age: 5
ID: 4444

The first error was that there was no newline after ID: 4444.  When I fixed that, I started getting the word NONE before ID:.  If I knew where it was coming from I could probably figure it out, but I've got nothing.  PLEASE HELP!!!

````
class AnimalData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.full_name = ''
        self.age_years = 0

    def set_name(self, given_name):
        self.full_name = given_name

    def set_age(self, num_years):
        self.age_years = num_years

    # Other parts omitted

    def print_all(self):
        print('Name:',  self.full_name)
        print('Age:', self.age_years)


class PetData(AnimalData):
    def __init__(self):
        AnimalData.__init__(self)
        self.id_num = 0

    def set_id(self, pet_id):
        self.id_num = pet_id

    # FIXME: Add print_all() member method

""" Your solution goes here"""

user_pet = PetData()
user_pet.set_name(input())
user_pet.set_age(int(input()))
user_pet.set_id(int(input()))
user_pet.print_all()```


I've been working on this assignment for 2 days and I'm getting errors no matter what I try.  At one point the word NONE was randomly appearing before ID: 4444, still can't figure out where it's coming from.  PLEASE HELP!!!! 

Here is some of what I've tried and the errors I got.

## 
No newline after ID: 4444
def print_all(self):
AnimalData.print_all(self)
print('ID:', self.pet_id)

## 
ID number not showing in output.
def print_all(self):
print(AnimalData.print_all(self), 'ID:', self.id_num)

## 
No newline after ID: 4444
user_pet = PetData()
user_pet.set_name("Fluffy")
user_pet.set_age(5)
user_pet.set_id(4444)
user_pet.print_all()
````

Comment: With correct indentation, your first attempt should work fine.

Comment: Why do you say there is no newline after the ID line? That call to `print` absolutely outputs a newline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a parent class's method from a child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-do-i-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-a-child-class-in-python)

Comment: @chepner those were the errors that zyBooks were giving.  when I went back to check the indentation i noticed the issue. I had pet_id instead of id_num.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @JonSG not even close, but thanks!

Comment: While correcting `pet_id` makes your code work, I don't believe you really want to call `AnimalData.print_all(self)` but rather `super().print_all()` as your class derives from `AnimalData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
def print_all(self):
    AnimalData.print_all(self)
    print('ID:', self.id_num)
```

Thanks for your help @chepner!!